# mysqli fetch_object returning non-object in the first element of the result set array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a particular mysqli query that returns an empty element at the 0th position in the result set array. This empty non-object element seems to cause problems when I try to loop through the result set to display to screen

```
$projAreas[] = array();
$projectID = $_GET['projectID'];

$sql = "SELECT *
       FROM  `areas` ,  `project_area_junc` 
       WHERE  `areas`.`areaID` =  `project_area_junc`.`areaID` 
        AND  `project_area_junc`.`projectID` = $projectID";

$results = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    $projAreas[] = $row;
    }
```

**The result gives unwanted array element at position 0)
i.e. when I print_r($projAreas)
I get this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [areaID] => 56
            [propertyID] => 14
            [areaName] => Living Room
            [areaInfo] =>  lots of windows - colonial style
            [proj_area_juncID] => 10
            [projectID] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [areaID] => 57
            [propertyID] => 14
            [areaName] => Kitchen
            [areaInfo] =>   
            [proj_area_juncID] => 11
            [projectID] => 4
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ....

```
 $projAreas = array();
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        array_push($projAreas ,$row);
        }

     print_r($projAreas);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$projAreas= array();`

instead of

`$projAreas[]= array();`

you have declare the array `$projAreas` as well initialize it by `[]` which takes first index 0

Comment: thanks, this works! , as you identified the problem was because I included the square brackets - I should have seen that, d'oh!